# IOS 8.1 Xcode 6 Dynamic Framework Storyboard rendering issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, uistoryboard

Ive converted an existing IOS project into a dynamic framework Using IOS 8.1-Xcode6 Dynamic Framework facility, All the storyboards in the application are now inside the framework bundle.The Storyboards of the app renders well Iphones of different screen size in in the project where im building the framework , but it fails to render its storyboards properly  on bigger Iphone screens when the framework is taken and embedded in a different project and used like an SDK.
Ive exposed a method in the framework which returns a reference of the mainStoryboard inside it .

```
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:frameworkBundle];
return sb;
```

Then in the host application, to render the hidden storyboard inside the framework the returned reference of the Mainstoryboard from the exposed API is used to set it to the presentView of the Viewcontroller of the host application .

The autolayout feature is turned on in both the projects . Why is it that the storyboard not rendering well on bigger screens in a different project where the framework is used as an SDK but it renders well in the project where im building the framework itself?